# pymysql fetch data iteration

Tags: python, pymysql

Iteration of each record then print by key display nothing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Print necessary headers.
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

import pymysql.cursors  
# Connect to the database.
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(db='candidate', user='root',passwd='123',host='localhost')
print ("connect successful!!")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT can_id,can_name,state,total_votes FROM voting")
result_set = c.fetchall()
for row in result_set:
    print(row["can_id"])
```

print(row) works fine

Answer (score 2):

```
c = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

or

```
conn = pymysql.connect(db='candidate', user='root', passwd='123', host='localhost', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose some changes using the [PyMySQL documentation](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html) as reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- conding: utf-8 -*-
# Print necessary headers.
print("Content-Type: text/html")
import pymysql.cursors  
# Connect to the database.
# That is important: the order of connection parameters
# 1st host, 2nd user, ...
conn = pymysql.connect(
    host='localhost'
    user='root',
    password='123',
    db='candidate',
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor # <-- declare cursor class
)
print ("connect successful!!")
try:
    with conn.cursor() as c:
        query = "SELECT can_id, can_name, state, total_votes FROM voting;"
        c.execute(query)
    with c as pointer:
        for row in pointer.fetchall():
            print("Name: %s" % row['can_name'])
finally:
    conn.close()
```